# Is there a way to extend the SASS preprocessor to manipulate arbitrarily each declared property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

I am developing an embeddable widget that needs to have all its CSS properties declared as important to prevent CSS bleed of the embedding page. This means that if I want to use some pre-existing CSS framework (like Bootstrap), or some jQuery plugin that uses a CSS stylesheet,  I have to manually copy-paste the CSS in my assets folder and add `!important` declarations to each property. This seems a rather unmaintainable and error prone process.

**As per title, is there a way to extend the SASS preprocessor to add `!important` to any declared property for an imported file or partial?**

Comment: I offer this as a comment since it does not directly answer your question. If you need to add `!important` to everything, then there seems to be something fundamentally flawed in the design scheme of your widget. You should be able to build a widget that uses normal selector precedence of ids and classes to work around "CSS bleed" and avoid any need for `!important`. Your idea seems analogous to a surgeon using a chainsaw to extract a sliver.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to address is the case where the embedding page declares some important properties on it's own, therefore overriding my non-important properties, even if correctly specified inside nested selectors with ids/classes.

Comment: I do sympathize with that situation. The proliferation of poor css (where people misuse `!important`) does create the need to overcome such conflicts. I gather from your proposal, however, that your intent is not to override only those that have `!important` declared, but to simply declare all yours `!important` whether or not it is needed, is that correct? Specifically when you are using classes from Bootstrap, etc.

Comment: That is correct. And I am afraid that detecting which properties are important and overriding them would be actually a bigger effort.

Answer (score 1):

No, 
Sass doesn't have that functionality, because it is the most uncommon thing you would want to do in Sass, or CSS, or anywhere for that matter.

However, from what I understand, you want to add in the `!important` to all the CSS properties in a particular file. In that case, you can just simply do a Search & Replace:
Search for `;` and replace with `!important;`

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to create a new mixin, potentially with the word `important` appended like so:

```
%margin-none-important {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

And then in your code:

```
.no-margin {
    @extend %margin-none-important;
}
```